# Spring Converter, Validator and DataBinder: how to handle multivalued bean fields individually?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've got a bean that has a field of type List among other things.

```
  public List<MyClass> getter() {
    return field;
  }

  public void setter(MyClass[] source) {
    this.field = Arrays.asList(source);
  }
```

I've implemented a converter `Converter<String, MyClass>` and it works, too. If a string can be converted into MyClass, it's converted, and if not, an exception is thrown, and an instance of `FieldError` is included in `Errors errors = binder.getBindingResult();`. The problem is, the `FieldError#getRejected` method a `String` with a comma-separated list of both valid and invalid values, which can be misleading. And without a space, which is just ugly. Like this:

```
Field has invalid value of "valid,invalid"
```

while I would prefer

```
Field has invalid value of "invalid"
```

In other words, how to get the conversion and validation to work individually on each value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although spring's approach is not very intelligent, it's logically correct. The following code can help you find the invalid value.

```
            FieldError fieldError = bindingResult.getFieldError();
            if (fieldError != null && fieldError.contains(TypeMismatchException.class)) {
                TypeMismatchException typeMismatchException = fieldError.unwrap(TypeMismatchException.class);
                ConversionFailedException conversionFailedException = findConversionFailedException(typeMismatchException);
                if (conversionFailedException != null) {
                    Object value = conversionFailedException.getValue();
                    // get the invalid field value
                }
            }
```

```
    /**
     * Recursively find the ConversionFailedException
     * @param target
     * @return
     */
    public ConversionFailedException findConversionFailedException(Throwable target) {
        Throwable cause = target.getCause();
        if (cause == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (cause instanceof ConversionFailedException) {
            return (ConversionFailedException)cause;
        }
        return findConversionFailedException(target);
    }
```